# Understanding a tricky case under the Java memory model in the presence of serialization

Tags: java, memory, serialization, garbage-collection

Hi I'm having trouble understanding how the following code will behave under serialization.

Foo is created as a temporary object and ends up being used in the method of an anonymous descendant of Bar. Bar is a field and survives the method creating the Foo object.

How is the Foo object stored. Is it a "implicit field" of the bar object? Is it an "implicit field" of the Program object? Does it just float around on the Heap while being referenced only in the code of the Bar::doSomething implementation?

I'm assuming that the garbage collector is smart enough not to delete this object. But will the Bar object after being serialized and deserialized still point to the same object? Foo isn't serializable and therefore cannot be serialized itself.

For those wondering, the sample is derived from a Wicket application that I'm writing and Foo and Bar are Models in my case. Therefore Foo is also serializable, but the question seems even more interesting when Foo isn't serializable.

```
class Foo {
  public void doSomethingElse() {
  }
}

abstract class Bar implements Serializable {
  public abstract void doSomething();
}

class Program {
  Bar bar;

  void main(String[] args) {
    otherMethod(new Foo());
  }

  void otherMethod(Foo foo) {
    bar = new Bar() {
      @Override
      public void doSomething() {
        foo.doSomethingElse();
      }
    };
  }

  // much later after bar has been serialized and deserialized
  void calledMuchLater() {
    bar.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your program doesn't even work. `main` is not a static method. Please provide a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: It also won't compile because the `Foo` parameter isn't `final`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would actually have two problems here.  The first is that the instance of the Bar class that you are creating is an inner class of Program, and Program is not serializable.  If you attempt to serialize the anonymous inner class you'll get an error even without worrying about Foo.

When you create an anonymous inner class, any of the variables referred to in the code of the class are copied into the class via a constructor that is transparently generated by Java.  Those variables become instance fields of that class, and therefore must be serializable in order to serialize the class.

Comment: `"When you create an anonymous inner class, any of the variables referred to in the code of the class are copied into the class via a constructor that is transparently generated by Java. Those variables become instance fields of that class, and therefore must be serializable in order to serialize the class"` This made it perfectly clear to me

Answer (score 0):

This will not work if `Foo` is not **serializable**. You would get an `java.io.NotSerializableException`.

If the `Foo` is serializable, then it will be serialized together with `Bar` and deserialized successfully.

---

> How is the Foo object stored? Is it a "implicit field" of the bar object?

Not sure exactly how, and I think it does not matter. What matters is that it gets stored (iff `Foo` is serializable; otherwise you get an exception as I said above).

> Does it just float around on the Heap while being referenced only in the code of the Bar::doSomething implementation?

It does not float around, it has it's place on the heap. And Garbage Collector will not pick it up as long as there are live references to this object. Since `foo.doSomethingElse()` references real foo object on the heap it will stay there (actually, this is one of the ways to create a memory leak).

> But will the Bar object after being serialized and deserialized still point to the same object?

No. A new object of the type `Bar` will be created, reverting the state of the serialized object.

Comment: I still don't understand how a memory leak occurs. Is it just that Program holds a reference to a Bar object that may not be needed at some point? Or is there some object floating around that is impossible to use, but still not garbage collected?

Comment: Memory leaks in Java are different from other languages (like C) where the programmer must be careful to free up memory that is allocated by the program but no longer needed.  Garbage collection theoretically helps with most of the common problems by cleaning up objects that are no longer referenced in the program, and freeing up the memory that was allocated for them.  The only real way to create a memory leak in Java is to allocate objects that you don't need and/or keep them around after they are no longer useful.  One common way is storing objects in a collection that aren't needed.

Comment: The object created is of an anonymous subtype of Bar.